# copy text automatically on mobile JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function copy() {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(newPassword);
    window.alert("Sua senha foi copiada!");
}
```

Hi, is my firts time publishing in this site, i was try to make a randon password generation but my problem is, when someone click in te text using a phone is not copied, but in the descktop works, somone culde help me plase.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.